# OSError when installing libraries with pip.exe

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip, access-denied

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an `OSError`:
OSError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе: 'C:\\Users\\Arnold\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-o43r1hbu\\pip.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Please tell me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you do not have a correct rights to install packages.
Did you try to do:

```
pip install "your_package_name" --user
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution may be (if you have the right permissions) to run command prompt as administrator. That should give you the right permissions to install packages.